# vba - why does userform come up twice after closing thisworkbook

Tags: vba, userform

I created a simple userform for testing, but one issue comes up and i have no idea how to resolve it.

This is the case:
When I open .xlsm file for the first time and close the userform and workbook, this closes both of them.
But when I continue to click the .xlsm file again, close the userform and the workbook, it (the userform) pops up again.
It seems the workbook doesn't close.
Then i need to close the userform again to close this workbook.

I would like help to understand why the userform comes up again?

The userform only has one listbox controls.
The following code is in a module:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
   
   UserForm1.Show
   MsgBox "Close2"
   ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

The userform contains the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Application.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
     MsgBox "Close1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the userform modal? For me, if it isn't; the document closes, I get the "Close2" and as soon as I click "OK" the useform is terminated, and no "Close1". Otherwise the document seems to close, but the Useform keeps anything else from triggering. When it's closed, "Close1" triggers followed by "Close2". Which seems to make sense. Are you saying you get the UserForm twice?

Comment: @Christofer Weber ,it is userform modal. yeah .I am saying I get the UserForm twice. I  drew a userform with listbox only . Then when i open xlsm file , i click the x button on this userform , both "Close1" and "Close2" come up and the file is closed . but when I click xlsm file again and repeat the above action(click the x button) ,  "Close1" and "Close2" come up and click "ok" , but at once the userform comes out again . So I am saying I get  the  UserForm twice.

Comment: I don't want to add as an answer as it's more of a suggestion.... use a variable to reference the form from a module:  `Dim MyForm As UserForm1: Set MyForm = New UserForm1: MyForm.Caption = "First Form": MyForm.ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!A1:A4": MyForm.Show`.  With `ShowModal` set to False you could open the form twice at the same time by repeating the above code and changing the variable name.  If you change the `UserForm_QueryClose` to `Msgbox Me.Caption` it will tell you the caption of the closed form when it closes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put this into the workbook code section as followed.
And not put it in a separate module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Visible = False
   userform1.Show
   MsgBox "Close2"
   ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

you can remove the code for the user form initialize.

The thing is as its hidden you might open it twice cause you do cause it does not respond directly.